# Excel to replace cell value based on lookup in another sheet

Tags: excel

Cannot figure this out, I searched for hours and tested using vlookup.

I want to change or replace the value of cells in column A in sheet1 if value in column P is found in column A located in sheet2.

I get it close to what I want but I get blank cells when no match is found. I need the cells in column A to keep their original value if no match has been found.

Formula I used:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P2,sheet2!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE),"")
```

Sheet1:

```
         A              P
 1 [References]---[ID numbers]
 2 [  000001  ]---[   123    ]
 3 [  000002  ]---[   456    ]
 4 [  newref  ]---[   999    ]
 5 [  000003  ]---[   789    ]
```

Sheet2:

```
         A              B
 1 [ID Numbers]---[References]
 2 [   123    ]---[xxx-000001]
 3 [   789    ]---[xxx-000003]
 4 [   456    ]---[xxx-000002]
```

Result sheet 1 should be:

```
         A              P
 1 [References]---[ID numbers]
 2 [xxx-000001]---[   123    ]
 3 [xxx-000002]---[   456    ]
 4 [  newref  ]---[   999    ]
 5 [xxx-000003]---[   789    ]
```

If this is not possible to achieve maybe using a prefix could work? Like adding (xxx-) when a match is found?

I appreciate your pointers, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have to change the original value in Col A in Sheet1 to the formula, it can never "keep it's original value".

You'll have to add another column with the original values of `A` (it can be hidden, but it has to be there)

Let's assume Col `Q` holds the original values of `A`, in cell `A2` the formula should be: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(P2,sheet2!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE),Q2)` and assuming `Q2` holds `newref` or `A2 original value` it should work for you

```
       A              P            Q
1 [References]---[ID numbers]---[original values]
2 [  000001  ]---[   123    ]---[hello]
3 [  000002  ]---[   456    ]---[world]
4 [  newref  ]---[   999    ]---[newref]
5 [  000003  ]---[   789    ]---[loremipsum]
```

BTW - if what you really want is either the value from `sheet2` or the explicit string `newref` you could simply do `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(P2,sheet2!$A$2:$B$13,2,FALSE),"newref")`

also note I used `IFNA` instead of `IFERROR` for a more accurate result (for example `#REF` errors will be replaced to `newref` when using `IFERROR`

Comment: Thank you, I start to understand now. 
In my test workbook it totally works but not when I apply this solution to my production workbook which uses imported xml data. 
In this case, adding column Q does not copy the values of column A to Q. Q values become "=[@References]" (refers to heading of column A). So i kinda get stuck in a loop of reference. I am using vba to perform other calculation on this workbook and sheet1 values are updated on regular basis. I guess I need to find a way to copy values of column A to column Q without referring to it. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: if the XML is fixed, you could go about it a different way and move the calculations to a different column (Q in the excel, which doesn't exist in the XML for example)

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just saw your edit.
What i really want is to change values from say 00001 to xxx-00001 in column A sheet1 only if column P matches the same ID number in sheet2.
 
Only sheet1 is linked to an XML file. Sheet1 has fixed columns headers and the cells content can be refreshed and changes. I guess i have to find a way to store values of column A to perform the lookup each time my XML is refreshed.